# As much as it may seem like it to me personally?

Tags: grammar

As much as it may seem like it to me personally, I feel desperately compelled to remind you that we are in fact not in prison.

1. Does 'as much as' mean 'although'?
2. I don't understand 'it may seem like it to me personally'.
   I thought 'it seems like + Noun/Noun Clause' is correct, but what is 'it seems like + it to me'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As much as **it** may seem like **it** to me personally, I feel desperately
>   compelled to remind you that we are in fact not in prison
>
> Does 'as much as' mean 'although'?

It does mean almost the same here.

> it may seem like it to me personally

This clause is interpreted like:

> This place may seem like prison to me personally.

The adjective phrase "like prison" functions as predicative complement in the structure of this clause. "To me personally" is one of those hedging expressions that qualify the entire content of the sentence.

The first "it" in the sentence stands for the place which was referred to in the previous context.

The second "it" is "cataphoric", which means that it comes before its antecedent. The antecedent "prison" is found in the following main clause.

Of course, pronouns are typically used "anaphorically" - we use them to refer BACK rather than AHEAD to their antecedent - but they are often used cataphorically as well, as shown in this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

`As much as` [compares two things](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-and-as-expressions/as-as) as the same (uncountable) quantity or amount. In this case it is saying that the two `it`'s appearing in the clause seem alike. The first `it`, in `it may seem`, refers to the circumstances. The second `it`, in `like it` refers to `being in a prison`.

You are right that there is an implicit `although`. It could also be a `but`, or an `even if` being omitted.

With `although`:

> `Although` (the circumstances) look **as much as** (being in a prison) to me personally, I feel desperately compelled to remind you that we are in fact not in prison.

With `but`:

> (The circumstances) look **as much as** (being in a prison) to me personally, `but` I feel desperately compelled to remind you that we are in fact not in prison.

With `even if`:

> `Even if` (the circumstances) look **as much as** (being in a prison) to me personally, I fell desperately compelled to remind you that we are in fact not in prison.

Comment: I cannot embrace any of these rephrasings, much as one might press me to do so.